# 100% width top bar – doesn't work

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to make a topbar that takes all width of the screen with css.
Today I decided to try Bootstrap and my standard way doesn't work:

style.css:

```
#topbar{
    width:100px;
    height:30px;
    color: #000000;
}
```

HTML:

```
<html>
<head>

    <title>Wave Magazine | Site with style.</title>
    <!-- JavaScript -->
    <script src="js/bootstrap.js"></script>
    <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <!-- Le styles -->
    <link href="css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" >

</head>
<body>
 <!-- topbar -->
    <div id="topbar">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="span4">
                    BlaBlaBla
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>                      
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You've given the width as 100px, which will be fullscreen if your screen is 100px wide. You probably want 100%.

Comment: @metrampaz Glad to be able to help! Welcome to StackOverflow!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your topbar CSS should actually say 100% instead of 100px. Also, you have linked the bootstrap.css file twice.

```
#topbar{
    width:100%;
    height:30px;
    color: #000000;
}
```

**Edit:**

Also try adding `type="text/css"` to your linked in css tags.

Comment: When I had 100px nothing appeared, after switching to 100% there's nothing either. Deleting surplus bootstrap.css link also changed nothing. Are there any other solutions that come to your mind?

Comment: @metrampaz Is there any other css?

Comment: No, just style.css which contains only #topbar and twitter's bootstrap.css  EDIT: I put color instead of background-color.